# Vue 3 globalProperties reactivity

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I try to migrate Vue 2 plugin to Vue 3, and in install function i have construction like this:

```
install(Vue, options) {
  const reactiveObj = {
    // ...
  };

  Vue.prototype.$obj = Vue.observable(reactiveObj);
}
```

And then I can access it with `this.$obj` in any component and it is reactive when `reactiveObj` changes. But in Vue 3 I try to make something like this:

```
import {reactive} from 'vue';

install(app, options) {
  const reactiveObj = reactive({
    // ...
  });

 app.config.globalProperties.$obj = reactiveObj;
}
```

And then I can access it with `this.$obj`, it is Proxy object, but it is not reactive when `reactiveObj` changes. How can I make it reactive?

Comment: Could you please post the code that you change ```reactiveObj```. I mean that how you change the ```reactiveObj``` and expect to be reactive? Do you change it inside your plugin or in your component and how?

Answer (score 1):

I post the codes that works for me when I changing the value of `$obj` in my component. Maybe it could help you to understand the problems in your code. here is the `"myPlugin.js"` file where I defined the plugin:

> myPlugin.js:

```js
import {reactive} from 'vue';

export default {
    install(app, options) {
        const reactiveObj = reactive({
            id: 1,
            name: "my-name"
        });

        app.config.globalProperties.$obj = () => {
            return reactiveObj
        };
    }
}
```

And here is the registration of plugin in my `main.js` file:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'

import App from './App.vue'

import myPlugin from "./plugins/myPlugin"

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(myPlugin);
app.mount('#app')
```

And here is the code of my component where by clicking the button the values of `$obj` is changed and you can see that it is `reactive`:

> component.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ $obj() }}</p>
    <button @click="myFunc">click to change</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {getCurrentInstance, reactive} from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const thisApp= getCurrentInstance()
    const reactiveObj1 = reactive({
      id: 2,
      name: "new-name"
    });

    const myFunc = function () {
      thisApp.appContext.config.globalProperties.$obj().name = reactiveObj1.name
      thisApp.appContext.config.globalProperties.$obj().id = reactiveObj1.id
    }

    return {
      reactiveObj1,
      myFunc
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

I used `getCurrentInstance` in my component, because I am using **composition API** style. Maybe you do not need that if you are using "options API" style.